# Spring scala object remove final modifier from class

Tags: spring, scala, final, companion-object

I'm writing a **Spring** application in SCALA. I had to change

`class Application {}` to `object Application {}`

to make the generated `main()` **static**.

```
@SpringBootApplication
@ComponentScan
@EnableAutoConfiguration
@EnableConfigurationProperties
@Import(Array(classOf[CoreConfiguration]))
object Application extends App {
  override def main(args: Array[String]): Unit = {
    val appCtx = SpringApplication.run(classOf[Application], args: _*)
  }

}
```

which causes SPRING to complain about **final** class  (final class Application):

```
BeanDefinitionParsingException: Configuration problem: @Configuration class 'Application' may not be final. Remove the final modifier to continue.
```

How can I create a Spring Application class in SCALA?

Answer (score 1):

Create a **companion object** i.e. a companion Application object in the same file. The result would be something similar to:

```
@SpringBootApplication
@ComponentScan
@EnableAutoConfiguration
@EnableConfigurationProperties
@Import(Array(classOf[CoreConfiguration]))
class Application {
  def run(args: Array[String]): Unit = {
    val appCtx = SpringApplication.run(classOf[Application], args: _*)
  }

}

object Application extends App {
  override def main(args: Array[String]): Unit = {
    new Application().run(args)
  }
}
```